# How to apply schema on the fly with Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, soap, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a web service that receives SOAP messages and with the aid of XJC I was able to partially convert these to pojos and then use the kafka json serializer to send said messages to Kafka.

I am now trying to streaming the messages using kafka and then ultimately persist to a data lake.

The requirement is to at least have some structure to the data in the data lake. However, because the initial schema is given in 2 xsds which are cyclically dependent, I haven’t been able to find a solution on how to apply structure to the data as it streams in. I am aware of inferring a schema given a batch of the messages but I don’t have enough sample data at this time.

One point to note is that, that messages vary per the original schema as it has `<choice>` elements and so each message may not be the same. How can I achieve structuring to this data given the limitations I’ve outlined above? I didn’t think to attach any code as this is more of a plan of attack as opposed to an issue with the code at this moment. Hopefully this is within guidelines and someone can help me get this project going. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, unfortunately as much as I dislike xsd and xml, the source data is defined and transmitted with these requirements so the challenge is to find a solution that can leverage kafka while transforming the data. Is there a way to define the schema with the avro format directly from xml/xsd?

Comment: Using the plugin in my answer (which I haven't used, so YMMV), from what I understand, you send an XML string directly into Kafka, from which, it then converts into an internal Struct Kafka Connect object. Then, you can use the `AvroConverter` (by Confluent), which then translates to Avro. And NiFi/StreamSets can do similar things via their own internal data formats/converters/processors. Point here - Spark isn't the only option available, and I personally recommend not reinventing the wheel here by writing your own code to do so

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want a well-defined, evolving schema that can work well with Datalakes (HDFS, S3, etc), I suggest [using Avro via the Confluent Schema Registry](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one) instead of JSON. You could even use the [`KafkaAvroSerializer`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#serializer) rather than the JSON one that you are currently using.

Avro isn't a requirement for Kafka, but this will also you to more easily use the Kafka Connect Framework to write to HDFS or S3, and query this data using SQL tools like Hive/Presto/SparkSQL. Kafka Connect would be preferred here because there is no streaming code you actually have to write.

If you want to work with XML and XSD schemas, take a look at [kafka-connect-xml](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml) transformer

Other alternatives for Datalake ETL with good XML support that I've come across are NiFi and StreamSets.